# Reference node inherits taxonomy terms of referenced node

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

This is a problem that's been bugging me for days now and haven't yet found a solution in Drupal 7.

I'll be more specific:

I have a content type named Debate and another one called Vote. 
Vote type has a node reference field to Debate type.

Debate type has a term reference field (autocomplete widget, 4 values, Voting choices vocabulary) where user inserts the voting choices of his Debate node.

Vote type has a term reference field (select list, 1 value, Voting choices vocabulary) where user can choose a term to vote.

My problem is that the select list of the term reference field of the Vote node shows all the terms of the Voting choices vocabulary. What I want is the select list of the Vote node to show only the terms that come from the Debate node it's referring to.

In other words I need to filter out the terms of the Vote node based on the Debate node it's referring to, when I'm at the node/add/Vote form of course.

Comment: this would require a bit of back end coding is that something you are comfortable with?

Comment: Hello Mohammed thanks for the prompt reply. Please feel free to show me the code and i'll give my best to understand and apply it.

Comment: You can use the hook_form_alter() to restrict the values from this field in the node form. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Comment: Thanks but please be more specific. Also note the following link: http://voices.yahoo.com/drupal-combining-taxonomy-node-reference-4550961.html?cat=15 which describes exactly what i want to accomplish but in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would create a form alter function and make the taxonomy field as hidden and add ajax functionality to the node reference field. I am assuming that then node reference field widget is a select list.

For the following example I am assuming your fields are in the Basic Page. you can change the function name to suite your requirement by changing the mymodulename and page.

I am assuming the field name of the term reference field is field_vote and the node reference field is field_debate

```php
function mymodulename_form_page_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // We add the ajax functionality to the node reference field.
  $form['field_debate']['#ajax'] = array(
    // #ajax has two required keys: callback and wrapper.
    // 'callback' is a function that will be called when this element changes.
    'callback' => 'vote_field_return',
    // 'wrapper' is the HTML id of the page element that will be replaced.
    'wrapper' => 'replace_vote_div',
  );

  // Add a wrapper around the taxonomy field.
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="replace_vote_div">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  // Check the form state to see if the debate field is filled.
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_debate'])) {
    // Load the debate node.
    $debate = node_load($form_state['values']['field_debate']);

    $form['field_vote']['#type'] = 'select';

    // Assuming the taxonomy field in debate content type is field_vote_debate
    // Some times the language for the field might be different from the language of
    // the node itself in this case you might want to look at a dump of the $date
    // field and make the required changes. 
    foreach($debate->field_vote_debate['$debate->language'] as $vote_term) {
      $form['field_vote']['#options'][$vote_term['taxonomy_term']->tid] = $vote_term['taxonomy_term']->name;
    }
  }
  else {
    // Hide the taxonomy field to start of with.
    $form['field_vote']['#type'] = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

The call back function is pretty straight forward we simply return the field_vote so that it can be rendered again in the form

```php
function vote_field_return($form, $form_state) {
  // The form has already been submitted and updated. We can return the replaced
  // item as it is.
  return $form['field_vote'];
}
```

**Note: As per the comment Please find below the updated code if the node ID is coming from url**

I am assuming that the url to add the vote node is as follows

http://example.com/node/add/vote/23

where 23 is the node ID of the debate content type.

```php
function mymodulename_form_vote_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // We use the arg() function to get the argument from the url. The numbering
  // starts from 0 and the one we need would be at 3. 
  $debate = node_load(arg(3));



  // Assuming the taxonomy field in debate content type is field_vote_debate.
  // Some times the language for the field might be different from the language of
  // the node itself in this case you might want to look at a dump of the $date
  // field and make the required changes. 

  foreach($debate->field_please_vote['$debate->language'] as $vote_term) {
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($vote_term['tid']); 
    $form['field_vote']['und']['#options'][$vote_term['tid']] = $term->name;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Hey Mohammed thanks for the code. I forgot to mention though that my node reference field has the "from URL widget" and not select list. SO how does this change your code?

Comment: aha that would make it even more easier. since we might not need the ajax at all. and just one function would be enough. Just the form alter function. I have added that as well.

Comment: Thanks again Mohammed. So i assume that i will create a module and add the above code correct? Sorry with the dumb question just need to be sure. A last thing. What do you mean by: // Some times the language for the field might be different from the language of
  // the node itself in this case you might want to look at a dump of the $date
  // field and make the required changes.

Comment: you can create in either in a module or in template.php. As for language the main language of the node and the field might be different.

Comment: Hello there Mohammmed. I tried in template.php but gives me some errors. Here's the code i use:                              function bartik_form_vote_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 
  $debate = node_load(arg(3));

  $form['field_please_vote']['#type'] = 'select'; 
  foreach($debate->field_voting_choices['$debate->language'] as $vote_term) {
    $form['field_please_vote']['#options'][$vote_term['taxonomy_term']->tid] = $vote_term['taxonomy_term']->name;
  }  
}

Comment: could you tell me the error you are getting.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: taxonomy_term in bartik_form_vote_node_form_alter() (line 169 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mydebate\themes\bartik\template.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in bartik_form_vote_node_form_alter() (line 169 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mydebate\themes\bartik\template.php).
Notice: Undefined index: taxonomy_term in bartik_form_vote_node_form_alter() (line 169 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mydebate\themes\bartik\template.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in bartik_form_vote_node_form_alter() (line 169 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mydebate\themes\bartik\template.php).

Comment: what is the type of the field field_voting_choices? is it a taxonomy term reference or something else?

Comment: its a taxonomy term reference field with autocomplete widget.

Comment: can you change this $debate->field_voting_choices['$debate->language'] to $debate->field_voting_choices['und'] and then check.

Comment: ok. i will test it in a while and report back to you. thanks again

Comment: Still not working Mohammed. Got this repeating error:            Notice: Undefined index: taxonomy_term in bartik_form_vote_node_form_alter() (line 169 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mydebate\themes\bartik\template.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in bartik_form_vote_node_form_alter() (line 169 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mydebate\themes\bartik\template.php).

Comment: do one thing comment out the rest of the codes except the first one $debate = node_load(arg(3)); in the function and try to print the node object something like this. drupal_set_messgae("<pre>" . print_r($debate, true) . "</pre>"); then could you send me the out put of that

Comment: Ok i did it. It seems to have passed a long list of code to the vote form. It's to long to paste it here. Do you mind if i send it to you by email?

Comment: you can use http://pastebin.com/ send me the link

Comment: Ok here's the link: http://pastebin.com/SAaeNTz2

Comment: ok do one thing for now change the code to this. $form['field_vote']['#options'][$vote_term['tid']] = $vote_term['tid']; and check if you are getting the list of ids. if you get that let me know.

Comment: It's working great with tid's!

Comment: ok in that case i have edited code check that and let me know

Comment: Ok Mohammed. It's working great. But...whenever i try to save the vote node i get a webpage error kicking me out of my site. It's like it can't return me back to the node i just submitted. What's wrong?

Comment: can you show me the error?

Comment: It's the classic "The website cannot display the page" Http 500 error (This error -HTTP 500 Internal Server Error- means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.For more information about HTTP errors, see Help.)
It has options to referesh the page or go back to the previous page. When i refersh the page it takes me back to the blank vote node editing form.

Comment: can you do one thing can you print out the form variable just like we did for debate and send me through pastebin

Comment: Ok here you go: pastebin.com/wrCu92iu

Comment: that doesn't look like the form variable. it should be something like this. drupal_set_messgae("<pre>" . print_r($form, true) . "</pre>");

Comment: Sorry. Here's the correct one: http://pastebin.com/LWF3g4P7

Comment: you can remove the statement $form['field_please_vote']['#type'] = 'select'; and replace that with $form['field_please_vote']['und']['#options'] = array(); and then also change this $form['field_vote']['#options'][$vote_term['tid']] = $term->name; to $form['field_vote']['und']['#options'][$vote_term['tid']] = $term->name;

Comment: it's not working now. the selection options are not filtered. It shows all the terms in the list and not the corresponding debate's terms.

Comment: I had edited the comment I guess you did not notice that. Sorry about that. Please as in the comment. you need to add the statement $form['field_please_vote']['und']['#options'] = array(); before the loop.

Comment: It's finally working! Thanks Mohammed. One last thing please. It works fine when adding a new vote node but when i want to edit an existing vote node (let's say change my voting choice) i get similar errors like those we had in the begining and the "please vote" field has no options. How do you fix this?

Comment: I suppose you will not be having nid argument in that case. so you might have to check if the argument is present if not then you would load the nid from the form itself. and do it as we did not.

Comment: @BillyKouroublakis Comments are not for extended discussion; put the relevant information in the question. (The same is true for Mohammed Shameem, who should put the relevant information in his answer.)

Comment: Ok. Thank's for everything. You've been very kind and very helpful.